# How to find the options in if conditions of shell

Tags: bash, shell

In one of my shell script, I'm seeing

```
if [[ ! -d directory1 || ! -L directory ]] ; then
```

What does `-d` and `-L` option mean here? Where can I find information about the options to use in an `if` condition?

Comment: Those aren't `if` syntax; they're `[[` syntax. `[[` is a completely separate command from `if`.

Answer (score 12):

You can do `help test` which will show most of the options accepted by the `[[` command.

You can also do `help [` which will show additional information. You can do `help [[` to get information on that type of conditional.

Also see `man bash` in the "[CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html#lbBW)" section.

Comment: Is the backslash needed? I would expect `help [` to be fully equivalent.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I'm not sure why I escaped that seven years ago. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The `-d` checks whether the given directory exists. The  `-L` test for a symbolic link.

The [File test operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) from the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html) explain the various options. And here is the [man page for bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) which can also be found by typing `man bash` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` has built-in help with the `help` command. You can easily find out the options to a bash built-in using `help`:

```
$ help [[
...
Expressions are composed of the same primaries used by the `test' builtin
...
$ help test
test: test [expr]
    Evaluate conditional expression.
    ...
    [the answer you want]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bourne shell, `[` and `test` were linked to the same executable. Thus, you can find a lot of the various *tests* available in the [test](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html) manpage.

This:

```
if [[ ! -d directory1 || ! -L directory ]] ; then
```

is saying if `directory1` is not a directory *or* if `directory` is not a link.

I believe the correct syntax should be:

```
if [[ ! -d $directory1 ] ||  [ ! -L $directory ]] ; then
```

or

```
if [[ ! -d $directory1 -o ! -L $directory ]] ; then
```

Is the line in your OP correct?

Comment: The line in the OP is correct; you may be confusing bash syntax with POSIX syntax.  Bash's `[[` supports `||` and whatnot; POSIX `[` does not.  To do the same thing in POSIX shell, you'd do `if [ -d "${directory1}" ] || ! [ -h directory ]; then`.  The `-o` syntax is specified by POSIX, but it is obsolescent (it causes parsing ambiguities).